# While Loop doesn't break when error is occurred

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, while-loop

I want my while loop to break when there an error, but it doesn't break / close program when it does...

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def check_listing_sell():
    counter = 0
    house_counter = 0
    while True:

        url = f"https://www.remax-quebec.com/fr/courtiers-immobiliers/james.he/index.rmx?offset={counter}#listing"
        r = requests.get(url)

        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

            for item in soup.select("div.property-address"):

                house_counter += 1
                address_prospect = item.get_text(strip=True)
                print(f"{address_prospect} {house_counter}")

            counter += 12
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break


check_listing_sell()
```

Comment: Are you sure the exception is ocurring? I can't see any reason why it wouldn't break.

Comment: You probably want `requests.get(url)` inside the `try`

Comment: @Barmar Yes cause when I  run the program after three loop it stop printing data, and if I close manually the program it give met those error https://prnt.sc/VCOh5HbrzV1P . I also tried to put ```requests.get(url)``` inside ```try```, doesn't work

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows that the error is coming from `requests.get(url)`. Since it's not in the `try`, it doesn't get caught by `except`. Moving it should definitely fix the problem.

Comment: I already tried to put the ```requests.get(url)``` in the try statement before posting here. I just retried and it not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, `soup.select("div.property-address")` returns an empty webelements (not an error) even on 'no results' page. Thus, the condition `if len(soup.select("div.property-address")) == 0` should be added. Moreover, placing `r = requests.get(url)` inside the try block is a decent suggestion.

```
    while True:

        url = f"https://www.remax-quebec.com/fr/courtiers-immobiliers/james.he/index.rmx?offset={counter}#listing"

        try:
            r = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
            
            if len(soup.select("div.property-address")) == 0:
                break

            for item in soup.select("div.property-address"):

                house_counter += 1
                address_prospect = item.get_text(strip=True)
                print(f"{address_prospect} {house_counter}")

            counter += 12
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the call to `requests.get()` inside the `try`.

`KeyboardInterrupt` is not a subtype of `Exception`, so you need a separate `except` block for that.

```
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def check_listing_sell():
    counter = 0
    house_counter = 0
    while True:
        url = f"https://www.remax-quebec.com/fr/courtiers-immobiliers/james.he/index.rmx?offset={counter}#listing"

        try:
            print(url)
            r = requests.get(url)
            print(r.text[:30])
            # soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

            # for item in soup.select("div.property-address"):

            #     house_counter += 1
            #     address_prospect = item.get_text(strip=True)
            #     print(f"{address_prospect} {house_counter}")

            counter += 12
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Manual interrupt")
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception occurred for counter={counter}, stopping loop: {e}")
            break

check_listing_sell()
```

Comment: As mentioned above, it doens't work either. it give me the same error when I manually close the program. Does this fucntion work fine on your end?

Comment: You need to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` explicitly, I've updated the answer.